# Passing parameters from webpage to server (Flask)

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm just getting started with adding a backend into my front-end code and think flask is a good framework to start learning with.

One of the things I'm having trouble with is submitting information to the server for processing. Specifically here I have a list of radio buttons, and I want to send to a server a list of all the radio buttons the user checked when he or she hit submit. The server then processes that information and returns a new page.

This is the form:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('timeline') }}" method="post">
   {% for each_tag in tags %}
  <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="channel[]" value="{{each}}" >
        {{each_tag}} 
      </label>
  </div>    
{% endfor %} 

   <button type="submit"> submit </button>
</form>
```

Here are the relevant functions in the main flask file:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index.html')
def checklist():
    for rownum in range(1,sh.nrows):
        row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
        all_tags.add(row_values[7])

    return render_template('index.html', tags=all_tags)

@app.route('/timeline.html', methods=['POST','GET'])
def timeline(request):
    //do stuff with list of checked radio buttons
    return render_template('timeline.html')
```

I'm not exactly sure how information is passed back and forth. I can send server info to the html templates and I think once I get this example down and figure out how information is passed the other direction I can start doing some interesting things. =)

Comment: You may want to consider [WTForms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html) if you are doing forms.  It is pretty easy to work with and has nice helpers like form validation.  You can see an example of its use in [The Flask Mega-Tutorial, Part III: Web Forms](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naming the checkboxes with trailing square brackets (`"channel[]"`) is a PHP thing, Flask doesn't need that.

Just use the same name in all the checkboxes:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('timeline') }}" method="post">
   {% for each_tag in tags %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="channel" value="{{each}}" >
   {% endfor %} 
    <button type="submit"> submit </button>
</form>
```

Then to retrieve the array of selected values use `request.form.getlist()`:

```
@app.route('/timeline.html', methods=['POST','GET'])
def timeline(request):
    checked = request.form.getlist('channel')

    # do something with checked array

    return render_template('timeline.html')
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Can you also share how WTForms relates? I saw it a lot in my searches but it seemed like too heavy of a solution.

Comment: Flask-WTF/WTForms are not heavy, they greatly simplify form validation. If you just have a bunch of checkboxes there isn't much in the way of validation, but for more complex forms it'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: Ok, I'll be sure to look into them. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a great solution, but what about when they are just GET parameters?  In effect, how do request.args and request.form differ?